# MongoDB / MongoEngine: ValidationError at / [ObjectId('53f466e60ffa5927709972e8')] is not a valid ObjectId

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

How do I get the actual string ID from ObjectId('53f466e60ffa5927709972e8')?

This is the line that causes the error

```
humans = [humanInstance[0].id]
```

**Update**: I did

```
humans = [str(humanInstance[0].id)]
```

and now I get

```
['53f466e60ffa5927709972e8'] is not a valid ObjectId
```

Why is this not a valid ObjectID, and how do I get one? :/

Answer (score 0):

The good news is `'53f466e60ffa5927709972e8'` looks like a valid ObjectId string:

> a valid ObjectId (12 byte binary or 24 character hex string)

src: [PyMongo ObjectId](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.7/api/pymongo/objectid.html)

You can convert to string as you are doing or via:

```
"%s" % humanInstance[0]
```

Or to get a list use a comprehension:

```
["%s" human for human in humanInstance]
```

However, your error is because it expects `humans` to be an ObjectId or a convertible to an ObjectId (the string is fine) but you are providing a list!

```
['53f466e60ffa5927709972e8'] is not a valid ObjectId
```

Try setting `humans = '53f466e60ffa5927709972e8'` or changing your Document schema to be a `ListField` of `ObjectIdFields` or `ReferenceFields`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I realise I haven't mentioned but the schema is indeed Listfield(ReferenceField(human)). If I try without the list it says it expects a list or a tuple

Comment: Does passing instance work? eg: `humans = [humanInstance[0]]` If not can you provide examples of your model?